# boost mutex C++/CLI problems

Tags: multithreading, boost, 64-bit, c++-cli, mutex

I'm developing in Visual Studio 2008 C# for 64bit and I want to use to use a library which uses boost. So I wrote a wrapper in C++/CLI. I managed to target the error I get to

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>.
```

If I include any file in my C++/CLI wrapper that by itself includes `<boost/thread/mutex.hpp>` or if I include it directly in the wrapper I get a "System.AccessViolationException" "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

I was very carefull in building everything for 64bit so I doubt that the problems is there. When I use the same library in 64 bit in "plain" C++ everything works fine. I came over a couple of posts where people seem to have similar problems with boost threads but none of the solutions I found worked. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Do you mean `boost::asio` by a library using `boost::thread`? Anyway once I did want to use `boost::asio` and ended up with winsock in a native little library of mine to be wrapped by C++/Cli. I am sorry but `boost` is not the right library to directly contact with C++/Cli. Try to avoid it.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that boost.thread uses some `#pragma section` directives that are incompatible when built without /clr then statically linked to code that uses /clr.

I've heard that rebuilding boost.thread with /clr (i.e., pass `cxxflags="/clr"` when invoking bjam) fixes the issue, but I haven't tried it personally.

I assume that dynamically linking to boost.thread (rather than statically, which is the default for VC++; `#define BOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK` before including any boost headers) should work too, but again, I haven't tried it.

If that doesn't work, try googling for some combination of `boost` `thread` `clr` `tls`; you should find quite a few posts on the boost mailing list about it, as this is an **old** problem.

---

**EDIT**: As commented [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/04/29/c111417-features-in-vs-2015-rc/#comments) by Raman Sharma (a senior PM at Microsoft), even `std::mutex` isn't supported with /clr, so it's no real surprise that boost.thread's mutex implementation isn't either.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer says, boost's pragmas in tss_pe.cpp are incompatible with the CLR. A simple modification to that file fixes the issue though and will permit static linkage. My modified version for Boost 1.44 is [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/proteowizard/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/pwiz/libraries/boost_aux/libs/thread/src/win32/tss_pe.cpp) (diff versus [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/proteowizard/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/pwiz/libraries/boost_aux/libs/thread/src/win32/tss_pe-before_1_44.cpp) for changes made).

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Boost libraries must not be linked statically with the C++ CLI code otherwise the compiler can generate an incompatible image for some of the Windows versions.
As far as I am concerned, I had a hard time figuring out the issue when statically building with Boost 1.64 x86 thread library with VC++ 2017 under windows 10.
The binary worked fine under Windows 10 but raised a **System.BadImageFormatException** under Windows 7.
The issue was located in the Boost thread library which I initially statically linked to my C++ CLI assembly.

Here is a short code which easily reproduces the problem:

**testcli.h - C++ CLI assembly FAILURE code**

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libboost_thread-vc141-mt-1_64.lib") // static link makes the program crash under W7

namespace testcli
{
    public ref class TestClass { public: static void Test(){} };
}
```

**Program.cs - C# client code loading 'testcli'**

```
using testcli;

namespace Cli
{
    class Program { static void Main(string[] args) { new TestClass(); } } // instanciate C++ CLI Boost class 
}
```

The code above returns by raising a **System.BadImageFormatException** (the exception can be found in the Application Event Viewer).

If testcli is changed so that the Boost thread library is now linked dynamically:

**testcli.h - C++ CLI assembly SUCCESSFUL code**

```
#pragma comment(lib, "boost_thread-vc141-mt-1_64.lib") // dynamic link works fine under any Windows

namespace testcli
{
    public ref class TestClass { public: static void Test(){} };
}
```

The code now returns successfully.

Note that you can define BOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK instead of BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK as explained here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/thread/build.html

Doing so, you will not have to package all the Boost dynamic libraries with your application.