# Boost Threads with CLR

Tags: multithreading, boost, c++-cli, clr, boost-thread

Using Visual Studio 2008 and Boost Libraries 1.46.1 I want to compile and link the following with the /CLR flag:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
void run() {}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::thread t(run);   
}
```

The first error is about a forward-declared dummy-struct in boost::thread. [This post](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/291983)
works around this by declaring:

```
namespace boost {
    struct thread::dummy {};
}
```

Sure, I now can compile, but then I get the linker warning

**Warning   1   warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100001F) for 'boost.detail.win32._SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES'; image may not run**

Running the application results in

**The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).**

None of the suggestions in the previously mentioned forum thread works for me. I have built a static version of the Boost Threads lib, and it runs fine without the /CLR flag. Debug/Release makes no difference. I'm running under Win7 32-bit.

Any hints?

Comment: possible duplicate of [boost mutex C++/CLI problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5670248/636019)

Comment: @ildjarn: how is that? This is a linker error. The linked thread is a runtime error.

Comment: @Matt : "*The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).*" sounds like a runtime error to me.

Comment: @ildjarn: You're right. Who needs reading comprehension anyway? I think they are duplicates and the linker warning is a red herring.

Comment: Have you tried using boost in a DLL? I remember something about non-clr in a static lib linked to a clr exe not being possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already run into this problem, i don't remember where i got this but one workaround is declare "boost.detail.win32._SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES" after including all the boost headers like so.

```
namespace boost { 
    namespace detail { 
        namespace win32 { 
            struct _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES: public ::_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES {}; 
        };
    };
};
```

Remove the namespaces if you want everyone to see it.

Comment: Bingo! here is the original thread http://lists.boost.org/threads-devel/2009/10/0502.php