# Using boost in CLR

Tags: c++, boost, clr

I have problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104200/boost-threads-with-clr), but answer did not help.
I have some classes in h and cpp files(which uses boost), and main cpp file. Main cpp include these h files.
I include this in main cpp(like in the answer):

```
    namespace boost {
    struct thread::dummy {};
    namespace detail { 
        namespace win32 { 
            struct _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES: public ::_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES {}; 
        };
    };
};
```

And got rid of this:

**Warning 1 warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100001F) for 'boost.detail.win32._SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES'; image may not run**

But still get this: **The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)**

What's the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Solution](http://balon777.wikidot.com/0xc000007b):

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK
```