# How to link a C++/Cli project to a native c++ static library

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a static library (native c++).

Now I would like to use this static library in a C++/CLi project.

Compiling is ok, but there is a runtime error saying "ntdll.dll! ****memory access violation".

Both the static library and the clr project are using "/MD".

Is it valid to link a clr project to a native c++ static lib?
If yes, any special configurations I should pay attention to?

PS. I can't turn the static lib to dll.

Comment: It's likely some code is not being managed properly hence the access violation, possibly a marshaled string... Could be anything though

Comment: @Niall Thank you for replying. So nothing is wrong to link a clr project to a static c++ lib. It seems the program throws before it hits any of my own code.(according to the call stack)

Comment: I've never tried it; reduce the code to just a single empty function in the static library, build it, test it; then start to add code back, bit by bit. It could still be some static variable initialisation code that causes the issue.

Comment: I think it may be caused by boost.threading.

Comment: I'm not sure how, or if, boost and the CLI mix. You may need to custom build or provide some custom functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Linking `boost::thread` dynamically solves this problem.

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK
```

thanks to [Using boost in CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040273/using-boost-in-clr)