# c++ - cli application compiled on Windows 8 can not start on Windows Server 2008 R2 if boost/thread.hpp is included

Tags: visual-c++, boost, c++-cli, boost-thread

My application starts fine on my Windows 8 laptop.
However I can not start it on Windows Server 2008 R2. Following error occured:

```
The exception unknown software exception (0xe0434352) occured in the application at location 0xfd5ecaed.
```

The following is printed in the command line:

```
Unhandled Exception: Cannot print exception string because Exception.ToString() failed.
```

My solution contains one c++-cli project which i'm trying to use, and if I do not use it then everything works fine, so commenting just this line helps:

```
// private static CliAdapterMain cliAdapter = new CliAdapterMain();
```

I've tried:

- repair .NET Framework 4.5 on target machine
- repair/reinstall VS 2012 Update 1 Redistributable (both x86 and x64, version 11.0.51106.1)
- updated my VS2012 to Update 1 recompiled project
- no Windows pending updates, tried to reboot system several times

Dependency Walker claims that following DLL's are missing: `GPSVC.DLL IESHIMS.DLL MF.DLL MFPLAT.DLL MFREADWRITE.DLL WLANAPI.DLL` However they exist on target computer, for example here

```
c:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-grouppolicy-base_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_8649674dfda23046\gpsvc.dll
```

Probably I can try manually reregister missing dll's, but i don't think this is really a problem. Looking at an exception it seems that something is broken, not something is missing.

**upd:** From Windows logs:

Va.MBClient.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:
   at Va.MBClient.Program.Main(System.String[])

So I guess that `private static CliAdapterMain cliAdapter = new CliAdapterMain();` is failed but i don't know why.

**upd** played with my application a little. Finally i've found just one line of code that causes a failure. This is `#include <boost/thread.hpp>`. Why this doesn't work? I'm using latest version of boost (1.52), but i did built it on my Windows 8 machine. Should I rebuilt everything for Windows Server 2008 R2? Should I built entire project on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670248/boost-mutex-c-cli-problems  I had the same problem. I solved it by moving all code working with boost::thread to the separate native DLL.

Comment: @pogorskiy it's strange then that I can run on Windows 8 but can not run on Windows Server 2008 R2. because by this link people say that boost and CLR just not compatible.

Comment: the question is what about other parts of boost? If i will avoid boost::thread will other parts of boost library work fine with clr?

Comment: They write that the error is caused by specific `#pragma`s (`#pragma section(".CRT$XIU",long,read)` `__declspec(allocate(".CRT$XIU"))_PVFV p_tls_prepare = on_tls_prepare;`). Perhaps the behavior may vary depending on the platform. I strive to avoid the use of the system-dependent parts (such as a boost::thread or boost::asio) to get away from potential problems. It is better to move them to a separate native DLL

Comment: @pogorskiy i wanted to use boost because in future I need to port to Linux application that now I need to launch on Windows.

Comment: Use boost. Just separate the cross-platform kernel from the C++-CLI wrapper.

Comment: @pogorskiy what does it mean? should I create one pure c++ library and on clr library that refer that c++ library?

Comment: Yes, I solved the same problem in this way. Create a native С++ DLL library, hide the implementation details depend on Boost. Then, create a C++CLI wrapper for this library.

Comment: @pogorskiy do you know if I have to create native DLL or I can also create native Static Library?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to in the Windows Sever, some features is not enabled by default, you need to add the Windows Media Services and Wireless LAN Service by yourself to get the Dll back.

You can reference to [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730957.aspx)

Comment: are you sure I do need that? I don't use any "wlan" or anything like that.

Comment: This is based on what the depence worker reports, I have no idea in what is invoke in the code.

Comment: i see. sometimes application is able to work even when depence worker reports that dlls are missing. i will dig "0xe0434352" error code problem.

Comment: using Windbg , it can help you.